# Woocommerce Single Product page CSS not working

Tags: woocommerce

I am building an ecommerce website using Woocommerce and suddenly the Single Product Page has started behaving weirdly. The CSS doesn't seem to be working. I am getting a text only page without any styling.[image]

Comment: hard to say with the given info, if you open your inspector you should see which css files are loaded

Comment: I just inspected it with firebug and it shows "This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it.". I can't figure out what went wrong! :-(

Comment: I'm not familiar with woo commerce, do you download source files and produce the site in an IDE like visual studio or do you build the site online?

Comment: Well clearly your stylesheet didn't load, the question is how are you adding them?

Answer (score 0):

put < class "woocommerce" > in your content.

http://stanhub.com/how-to-fix-default-woocommerce-css-not-working-properly/

Comment: you may want to explain your answer a bit more.  putting 'woocommerce' in the content is open to interpretation and seems wrong to me.